# I have a problem with using multiple contexts of the same connection in EFCore. I would be very grateful if anyone could help me

Tags: c, .net

I encountered a problem using multiple contexts of the same connection in EFCore. The error message was:The specified transaction is not associated with the current connection. Only transactions associated with the current connection may be used.

First of all, I tested it with reference to the following documents.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions

```
 public void Get()
        {
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<testContext>()
            .UseMySql("Server=127.0.0.1;User Id=test;Password=test123456!;Database=test")
            .Options;


            using (testContext con1 = new testContext(options))
            {
                using (var transaction = con1.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    con1.User.Add(new User() { Address = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", Name = "aaaaaa", Tel = "1111111111" });
                    con1.SaveChanges();

                    using (testContext con2 = new testContext(options))
                    {
                        con2.Database.UseTransaction(transaction.GetDbTransaction());

                        con2.Userbook.Add(new Userbook() { Bookbar = "232323", Bookname = "1212", Userid = 1 });
                        con2.SaveChanges();
                    }

                    transaction.Commit();

                }              
            }
        }
```

An error occurred while running to: con2. Database. UseTransaction (transaction. GetDbTransaction ()).

The specified transaction is not associated with the current connection. Only transactions associated with the current connection may be used.

First, in the demonstration code, the two context instances of CON1 and con2 use the same connection object options, which conforms to the relevant syntax of EFCore and is consistent with the official DEMO notation of the above links, but I don't understand why there was an error in adding the DbContext. Database. UseTransaction (DbTransaction) API to register two contexts in the same transaction. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Probably you meant c#?

Comment: Yes, I use C# language.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do it like this. You are creating context `con1` and after that you are creating transaction from connection related win `con1`. That's why when you create `con2` and use transaction from `con1` you have an issue.

And for this test it is very strange to use transactions. Because, when you manipulate with data in the context it will work in one transaction. And when you call `SaveChanges` it is like commit for transaction.

Comment: According to the demonstration of official documents: You can now create multiple context instances that share the same connection. Then use the DbContext.Database.UseTransaction(DbTransaction) API to enlist both contexts in the same transaction.

Comment: So I'd like to try his way and see if I can register the same transaction under different contextual instances of the same connection.

Comment: You can open https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/save/transactions and see the test case of Cross-context transaction on this page, which is almost the same as what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved. The above case can run normally with SqlServer database, but the MYsql database will throw the above exception.